# behaviour of typeof in javascript

Tags: javascript, typeof

Can someone explain why **typeof** behaves in the following way:

```
typeof 
//Returns: SyntaxError: Unexpected token } (Quite obvious)

"Why am I a " + typeof 
//Returns: SyntaxError: Unexpected token }

"Why am I a " + typeof + ""; 
//Returns: "Why am I a number"

"Why am I a " + typeof + "??"; 
//Returns: "Why am I a number"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`+"..."` will actually parse the string as a number. This will result in `typeof + ""` returning "number", even though the returned number is `NaN`.

The first two usages are simply wrong, since `typeof` needs a right hand side.

#### References:

- [`typeof` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3)
- [Unary `+` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6)

Comment: Does this mean that the right side gets converted to function parameters? Does this happen with other JS functions too?

Comment: No. `typeof` isn't a function. It's an unary operator like `!`. Parenthesis around the right hand side of `typeof` are just additional sugar ontop of your cup of code.

Answer (score 6):

[typeof isn't a function but a unary operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3), so

```
typeof + "";
```

is the same as

```
typeof (+ "");
```

and `+something` converts the `something` to a number as is precised in [EcmaScript norm on the unary + operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.6) :

> The unary + operator converts its operand to Number type.

Comment: oh. didn't know about it! Does it happen with other JS functions too? (the conversion of `func + ""` to `func(+ "")` ?? or is it just specific to `typeof`?

Comment: @gopi1410: It's logically the same, not syntactically, since `typeof` is an operator.

Comment: [typeof isn't a function but an operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.4.3)

Comment: @gopi1410: `typeof` is not a function, it's an operator. The only way for `typeof + ""` to be valid JS is to interpret `+` as unary operator, and that's what the interpreter is doing. It's the same as if you multiply a negative number: `5 * -3`. This is interpreted as `5 * (-3)`. The `-` can only be a unary operator in this case.